# JavaScript innerHTML function issue

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Not sure if it is weird or simply I am stupid, but I am having an issue in JavaScript innerHTML. Ok, I hve an empty DIV in my body tag. What I want is to write an unordered list in it. So, I made this:

```
<script>
var bla = document.getElementById("bla");
bla.innerHTML = "<ul><li>LOL</li></ul>";
</script>

<div id="bla">

</div>
```

Hmm nothing is appearing in the DIV.. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id='bla' was not found because you script above the id and not use any function

change like this

```
<div id="bla">

</div>

<script>
var bla = document.getElementById("bla");
bla.innerHTML = "<ul><li>LOL</li></ul>";
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){var bla = document.getElementById("bla");
bla.innerHTML = "<ul><li>LOL</li></ul>";
 };
</script>

<div id="bla">

</div>
```

Comment: Really? this looks like it should work. Did you try running the code in the JavaScript console as a sanity check? `var bla = document.getElementById("bla");
bla.innerHTML = "<ul><li>LOL</li></ul>";` Are you sure the code is actually being called and that there isn't another onload callback overwriting this one? Put an alert or something in that onload to convince yourself that it's actually the innerHTML that's the problem and not that your callback is being hijacked.......

Comment: now it works lol, I forgot to add (); in the function lo..thank

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="bla">

</div>
<script>
var bla = document.getElementById("bla");
bla.innerHTML = "<ul><li>LOL</li></ul>";
</script>
```

Comment: if you will write/execute the script before <div id="bla"></div> then page will not find any id "bla" with this name as  div with id bla has not uploaded yet. so either use above one or <script>
window.onload=function(){var bla = document.getElementById("bla");
bla.innerHTML = "<ul><li>LOL</li></ul>";
 };
</script>